# Read Received via SPI data with arduino mega

Tags: c++, arduino, spi

There

I am working on one of the project, in that i am trying to read 16-bit data from [ADS8681](https://www.ti.com/product/ADS8681). Currently i get the correct waveform of SCk,MISO,MOSI and SCK on oscilloscope. But I am not able to print data on alphanumeric LCD. With readRegister(long thisRegister, long bytesToRead) also unable to print data. Can anyone suggest me how i print received data?

References which i am using:
1] https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/BarometricPressureSensor#code

Source Code :

```
 #include <SPI.h>
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

 #define SS 53    // CS/CONVST

 LiquidCrystal lcd (38,37,36,35,34,33);

 void setup()
 {
  lcd.begin(16,4); 
  SPI.begin();              
  digitalWrite(SS,OUTPUT);  
            
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  delay(10); 
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW); 
  writeRegister(0x14, 0x0001); //Write data range selection

  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  delay(10); 
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW); 
  writeRegister(0x10, 0x4100); //Write Data_OUT_CTRL

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print ("Data");
 }

 void loop() 
 {
 digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
 delay(10); 
 digitalWrite(SS,LOW); 
 writeRegister(0x14, 0x0001); //Write data range selection


 delay(100);
 }

 void readRegister(long thisRegister, long bytesToRead) 
   {

 } 

 void writeRegister(word thisRegister, word thisValue) 
 {

 }
```

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 could you suggest any updates on question?

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I have little experience regarding Arduino, just wanted to point out the incorrect tag. I think the rest of your question is fine, but I can't be sure if you're putting irrelevant information in the code since I don't know enough about the Arduino library to say.

Comment: your code does not even attempt to read.